# aws - How create request when partitions exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I create a table whith many partitions :

```
PARTITIONED BY (`year` string, `day` string, `month` string, `version_` string, `af_` string, `type_` string, `msm` string)
```

after that, I run :

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE mytable;
```

When I launch the preview of mytable, I had 0 rows. I try:

```
select * from mytable
```

Also no results.

One solution is to use alter table to add partitions with values, but should I create alter table befory every request ?!

Comment: Does `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` allow the query to work? What is displayed after `REPAIR TABLE` -- does it say that the partitions were found?

Comment: @John  I get this after repair table :                                                                                    Partitions not in metastore:                          traceroute_6:af_=4/type_=anchor/msm=1026355/year=2017/month=05/day=14/version_=1 traceroute_6:af_=4/type_=anchor/msm=1026355/year=2017/month=05/day=14/version_=2

Comment: @JohnRotenstein : I created the table and I used the alter table add partition as : ALTER TABLE traceroute_6 ADD PARTITION (year='2017',month='05',day='14', af_='4', type_='anchor',msm='1026355',version_='7') location 's3://alltraceroute/', I get  results as expected. Now, I don't know the source of the problem.

Comment: I don't think that is efficient to use alter table to set the values in the partition columns before each request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that your `PARTITIONED BY` statement has fields in a **different order** that your directory hierarchy:

```
PARTITIONED BY (`year` string, `day` string, `month` string, `version_` string, `af_` string, `type_` string, `msm` string)

af_=4/type_=anchor/msm=1026355/year=2017/month=05/day=14/version_=1
```

You can fix it by listing the fields in `PARTITIONED BY` in the **same order** as the directory hierarchy.

I did a small test where I had a partition working, but then recreated the table with a different order and it returned zero rows. (It also created new directories in the expected hierarchy -- weird!)